# ArcGIS Java ServiceFeatureTable query always returns only 1 feature

Tags: java, arcgis, arcgis-runtime

I am trying to query an ArcGIS Online feature layer using `arcgis-java` (ArcGIS Runtime) as below:

```
ServiceFeatureTable featureTable = new ServiceFeatureTable(this.SERVICE_FEATURE_URL);
QueryParameters query = new QueryParameters();
query.setWhereClause("1=1");
query.setReturnGeometry(true);
ListenableFuture<FeatureQueryResult> queryFeaturesAsync = featureTable.queryFeaturesAsync(query);
try {
    FeatureQueryResult result = queryFeaturesAsync.get();
    Iterator<Feature> iterator = result.iterator();
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Feature feature = iterator.next();
        System.out.println(feature.getAttributes());
        System.out.println(feature.getGeometry());
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But always it returns only one feature even though the layer has more than 1 feature. How can I get more than one feature?

Also I tried by setting the `setMaxFeatures` also but there is no effect.

The main thing is I am not creating the `FeatureLayer` and `MapView` objects and not adding the FeatureLayer on MapView. I just want to query the `ServiceFeatureTable`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's returning all the features, but you're only looking at the first one. Try changing `if`:

```
if (iterator.hasNext()) {
```

to `while`:

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
```

Comment: Thank you @Gary for finding the mistake.